# Exception Handling with the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using a port of the STL found [here](https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL) and trying to debug with a simple `try{...}catch{...}` loop. When compiling with the Arduino IDE, I get the error message

> exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable.

I'm not quite sure what this means. Can the Arduino simply not support exceptions? Or is `-fexceptions` a compiler flag I can enable?

Comment: It's just disabled and if you want to use it, you have to provide `-fexceptions` flag to the compiler.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already found out, add `-fexceptions` to the compiler flags. This can be done by modifying the `platform.txt` of your Arduino IDE installation.

See https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/platform.txt#L28. There is `-fno-exceptions` defined, so you have to remove that, too.

Comment: Perfect, this is the (complete) answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino is a very limited platform, and handling exceptions requires quite a bit of hidden code to properly unwind the stack wherever the exception occurs.

So the default is to turn it off and teach users to not use exceptions in arduino and instead other type of error handling.

Comment: The default is not to use STL neither.

Comment: It's not just the default; Arduino has no built-in support for the STL.